# how to exclude nested field in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have stored nested object in MongoDb database & wants to retrieve records by excluding specific field from database using java language.
The nested object data structure is as follows
{
   address:
        {
            city : "Pune",
            pincode :34243
        }
}

In mongodb it can be done as follows:-
 db.info.find({},{address.city:0})

But when i am trying to excludes nested field value using below query

FindIterable iterDoc = collection.find().projection(Projections.exclude("address.city")).sort(new Document("_id", -1));

The above query removes entire address object. Please correct me if i have done mistake in syntax

Comment: which mongodb framework are you using?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn:- Thanks for reply. Do you mean mongodb version? if it is , then mongodb version is v3.6.5